# Crontab generates a new files in home folder every run instead of outputting to log file I specified

Tags: centos, cron, logs, output

I am running CentOS 6 and have the following crontab set up using crontab -e on my user called USER1

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/wget -q http://localhost/blah1/parse.php >> /home/USER1/Dropbox/www/blah1/crontab.log 2>&1
*/9 * * * * /usr/bin/wget -q http://localhost/blah2/autocheck.php >> /home/USER1/Dropbox/www/blah2/crontab.log 2>&1
```

The php files are running on schedule but with each run they will generate a new file inside my /home/USER1/ folder, such that I end up with thousands of new files each time I check:

```
parse.php
parse.php.1
...
parse.php.9999
autocheck.php
autocheck.php.1
...
autocheck.php.9999
```

Each of these will contain the output from a run.
Both log files I specifically set to receive the output and errors are blank.

What am I doing wrong and how do I get it to output to where I want it?

Answer (score 2):

This is discussed in the `wget(1)` manual;

```
       When running Wget without -N, -nc, -r, or -p, downloading the same
       file in the same directory will result in the original copy of file
       being preserved and the second copy being named file.1.

...

       When running Wget with -r or -p, but without -N, -nd, or -nc, re-
       downloading a file will result in the new copy simply overwriting
       the old.
```

The following may work, but will leave you at the whims of timestamp checking and what the local and remote servers set for their time (you have NTP everywhere, right?)

```
wget -q -N http://... >> log
```

or if timestamps are a concern then instead see the `-O` option which will require setting the filename to clobber.